# Why can "bubo" ("owl") be feminine or masculine?

Tags: gender, vergilius

Why the occurrence of "bubo" in the Virgilius text is an hapax?

This text is the only one listed in Lewis & Short with "bubo" being feminine.
Usually, it's a masculine noun. So, it is an hapax.

Why?
It is a mistake? The hint of a variant in the use of the word, existing among the Roman population, but not attested in other texts? Is there a logical reason for "bubo" having 2 possible genders? Did it have any consequences in the gender of descent languages?

Is it common for a noun to have 2 possible genders in Latin, or exceptional?

> būbo, ōnis, masculine (**feminine only once** Vergilius A. 4, 462; cf. Serv. ad loc.;

I wonder that, because this word is listed as masculine and feminine in many dictionaries.

Comment: In case it helps someone, here are [the entry](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=bubo1&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) and [the passage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D450).

Answer (score 12):

The relevant passage is this one, from Aeneid IV.462-3:

> sōlaque culminibus fērālī carmine būbo
> saepe quer' et longās in flētum dūcere vōcēs
>
> *And the lone owl on the rooftops would cry out its mournful song, drawing out its long calls into an elegy.*

I can see a few possible reasons why Vergil chose to make this particular *būbo* a feminine one:

- Masculine wouldn't fit the meter—for these lines to scan, the second syllable has to be light, and *sōl**us**que* would be heavy. These sorts of changes are common in poetry: note also how there's only a single owl on multiple rooftops, even though logically one owl can be on only a single rooftop at a time.
- This whole passage is about Dido's madness, and Dido is female, so it's poetically appropriate to have the owl be female too.
- Many names of animals in Latin have "common gender", and can take either masculine or feminine adjectives: if it were a lone dog mourning on the rooftops, it could be either a *canis sōlus* or a *canis sōla*. *Būbo* is not one of these (it instead has "epicene gender"), but the idea of an animal name switching its grammatical gender based on the sex of its referent wasn't a foreign or uncommon one.
- Many other words for owls, such as *strix*, *noctua*, and *ulula*, are grammatically feminine.

Any or all of these might have weighed into his decision.

Answer (score 7):

*Since the Virgil's [passage](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.02.0055%3Abook%3D4%3Acard%3D450) in question happens to start with 'Tum' I have to contribute something...*

(This is not an answer but I see no way of putting this as a comment due to formatting issues.)

There appears to be no clarity on the issue, so the chances of getting a clear, authoritative answer are actually slim.

"The Royal Grammar, Commonly Called Lilie's Grammar, Explained ... By William WALKER (B.D., Schoolmaster of Grantham.)" has the following paragraph with regards to this usage:

[image: Excerpt from "The Royal Grammar, Commonly Called Lilie's Grammar, Explained ... By William Walker ... The Third Edition, with Amendments"]

[P. Virgilii Maronis Æneis. The Æneïd of Virgil, with Engl. notes [&c.] by C. Anthon. Ed. with alterations by W. Trollope](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=ohoEAAAAQAAJ&lpg=PA212&ots=eAVIzWFxRM&dq=%22solaque%20culminibus%20ferali%20carmine%20bubo%22%20feminine&pg=PA212#v=onepage&q=%22solaque%20culminibus%20ferali%20carmine%20bubo%22%20feminine&f=false) also mentions an opinion that 'sola bubo' is to be understood as 'sola *avis* bubo':

[image]

And, for what it's worth, there is a whole article called ["Dido and the Owl"](https://www.academia.edu/27707560/Dido_and_the_Owl_2016_in_P._Mitsis_and_I._Ziogas_eds._Wordplay_and_Powerplay_in_Latin_Poetry._De_Gruyter_107-30) by [Emily Gowers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emily_Gowers) that offers, what I would call, a *poetic* rather than a *scientific* interpretation (this is just an excerpt, there are a few pages dedicated to the topic):

[image: Dido and the Owl]

Comment: The weird thing about that, is that this hapax is included in dictionaries as a rule. They say that "bubo" can be used in masculine or feminine.